# How to create SQLite database forgn keys without reference table

Tags: sqlite, syntax, foreign-keys

i have a question about sqlite3 foreign keys   but i didn't test this.so i want to sure about this...

if i create a "**table A**" with a **foreign key reference ** from " table B**" **but "table B**" is not created already.can i create successfully **table A** with foreign key references **without create "table B**" ?

```
Create Table A(
  A_ID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  B_ID    INTEGER,
  A_DESCRIPTION    TEXT,

  FOREIGN KEY (B_ID) REFERENCES B(B_ID)
)
------------------------------------not created already---------------->
Create Table B(
  B_ID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  A_ID    INTEGER,
  B_DESCRIPTION    TEXT

  FOREIGN KEY (A_ID) REFERENCES A(A_ID)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you couldn't find the answer by simply running that code, but the answer is No.  The referenced table and PRIMARY KEY must exist to create a FOREIGN KEY.

Some older versions of SQLite read but ignored FOREIGN KEYs, but that has not been true for some time.

Comment: according to your experience how about in mySQL this situation ?

Comment: No SQL database should ever allow you to create a FOREIGN KEY without the PRIMARY KEY and its table already created in the database.  At the time of FOREIGN KEY declaration, the database should check all the values to ensure that the data is valid.  A database that does not work this way is, in my opinion, broken.